# Div Scrolling on IPad

Tags: asp.net, ipad, html, scroll

I am developing an app in ASP.net in which I enable the div property of overflow scrolling like `overflow-y: Scroll`. But when I run this app on the IPad, the scrolling on div is not smoothly working. Can you suggest me any plugin for smooth scrolling or any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [**jQuery Custom Scrollbar**](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller) plugin for your app.

[**SEE DEMO**](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html):

**OR**

[**EXAMPLE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/nwfpy/):

Answer (score 0):

Try the Touchwipe jQuery plugin? http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library